# i have a .ps1 file and that file searches for the project certificates expiry in my project and i use to run that script using batch script in jenkins

Tags: powershell

This is the ps1 script which is checking for the certificate expiry
`Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse -ExpiringInDays $num_days | Out-String` and im running this ps1 script from jenkins using batch file like:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive "%WORKSPACE%\X\email_certs.ps1
```

```
<#  Setup e-mail template #>
    $to = 
    $from = 
    $subject = *************** Certs Expiring Soon **********"
<# days before certs expire #>
    $num_days = 14

    $expired_certs = Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse -ExpiringInDays $num_days | Out-String

<# If no certs, write console message #>
    if (!$expired_certs) {
        $console_msg = "No certs expiring within $num_days days"
        Write-Host $console_msg
    }

<#  Send an e-mail if certs are expiring within $num_days days #>
    $body = $expired_certs

    if ($expired_certs){
        $console_msg = "Sending an e-mail...."
        Write-Host $console_msg
        $email = @{
        From = $from
        To = $to
        Subject = $subject
        SMTPServer = "smtp3.com"
        Body = $body
    }

    send-mailmessage -Priority High @email
    }
```

How to know the path which `.ps1` script is checking for the certificate expiry?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its better to use the powershell step directly.

```
steps{
   powershell script: 
         '''
         your stuff here
         '''
```

then you know the powershell code runs in %Workspace%